# SQL Server - Adding header and footer fields in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have data in following format from SQL table

```
Code       Name
-----------------------------
Finance    Bank Charges
Finance    Interest Charges
Finance    Other Charges
Insurance  Premium Charges
Insurance  Other Charges
-----------------------------
```

I need to add Header at the beginning of each group and Footer at the end of each group.

I need to get following output using SQL query.

```
Code       Name
-----------------------------
Finance    Finance Header
Finance    Bank Charges
Finance    Interest Charges
Finance    Other Charges
Finance    Finance Footer
Insurance  Insurance Header
Insurance  Premium Charges
Insurance  Other Charges
Insurance  Insurance Footer
-----------------------------
```

Awaiting for your reply.
Thanks.

Comment: Sample data would help.

Comment: This is something your presentation layer should do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps a simple `UNION ALL`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Code] varchar(50),[Name] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Finance','Bank Charges')
,('Finance','Interest Charges')
,('Finance','Other Charges')
,('Insurance','Premium Charges')
,('Insurance','Other Charges')


Select Seq=2,* from @YourTable
Union All
Select Distinct 1,[Code],[Code]+' Header' From @YourTable
Union All
Select Distinct 3,[Code],[Code]+' Footer' From @YourTable
Order by [Code],Seq
```

**Returns**

```
Seq Code        Name
1   Finance     Finance Header
2   Finance     Bank Charges
2   Finance     Interest Charges
2   Finance     Other Charges
3   Finance     Finance Footer
1   Insurance   Insurance Header
2   Insurance   Premium Charges
2   Insurance   Other Charges
3   Insurance   Insurance Footer
```

Comment: Good idea, +1 from my side

Comment: @Shnugo Sometimes, you just need a hammer.   Not elegant, but gets the job done.

Comment: Ask Thor about the elegance of a hammer ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need `rollup` :

ORIGINAL QUESTION ANSWER :

```
select code, sum(name)
from table t
group by rollup (code);
```

EDIT : Assuming you need individual rows also if so, then you can do :

```
select code, name
from (select distinct 1 as sort, Code, concat(code, ' header') as name
      from table t
      union all
      select 2, Code, cast(name as varchar(255)) -- This assumes name has numeric value so, casting is needed.
      from table t
      union all
      select distinct 3, Code, concat(code, ' footer')
      from table t
     ) t
order by code, sort;
```

Comment: What if `Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator` while the `Name` column seems to be a `VARCHAR` datatype

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible via SQL but here is a way you may find it helpful

```
WITH K AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY Code) RN
FROM T
)
SELECT Code, 
       Name, 
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 
                THEN Code + ' Header'
            WHEN RN = (SELECT MAX(RN) FROM K WHERE K.Code = KK.Code GROUP BY Code)  
                THEN Code + ' Footer'
            ELSE
            '' END AS Title
FROM K KK;
```

Results:

```
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
|   Code    |       Name       |      Title       |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
| Finance   | Bank Charges     | Finance Header   |
| Finance   | Interest Charges |                  |
| Finance   | Other Charges    | Finance Footer   |
| Insurance | Premium Charges  | Insurance Header |
| Insurance | Other Charges    | Insurance Footer |
+-----------+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY`

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE (Code VARCHAR(20),      Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TempTable VALUES
('Finance', 'Bank Charges'),
('Finance', 'Interest Charges'),
('Finance', 'Other Charges'),
('Insurance', 'Premium Charges '),
('Insurance', 'Other Charges')

SELECT X.* FROM 
    ( SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN 
        FROM @TempTable ) T
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT Seq, Code, Code + ' '+ Title AS Name  FROM ( VALUES(1,'Header'),(3, 'Footer')) AS HF (Seq, Title)
        WHERE T.RN = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2 Seq, T.Code, T.Name
    ) X
ORDER BY Code, Seq, RN
```

Result:

```
Seq         Code                 Name
----------- -------------------- ---------------------------
1           Finance              Finance Header
2           Finance              Bank Charges
2           Finance              Interest Charges
2           Finance              Other Charges
3           Finance              Finance Footer
1           Insurance            Insurance Header
2           Insurance            Premium Charges 
2           Insurance            Other Charges
3           Insurance            Insurance Footer
```